# Get a part from an HTML code to a string variable in C#

Tags: c#, html, string, split

I took the HTML code from an website and I want to get just a section from it. I have something like:

```
<html content>
<what i need>
<other html content>
```

I know that the content which I need starts with:

```
<div class="widget-title"><h3><span>Ultimele stiri:</span></h3></div>
```

and finish with:

```
</div></aside>
```

I also know that the content between these two sections is changing. How can I make a substring containing the content I need?

Comment: Parse it as xml and search for the node.

Comment: Or use a library like [`HtmlAgilityPack`](https://html-agility-pack.net/) to parse the HTML and search by the class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public string GetSubstringByString(string a, string b, string c)
        {
            return c.Substring((c.IndexOf(a) + a.Length), (c.IndexOf(b) - c.IndexOf(a) - a.Length));
            // Usage: GetSubstringByString("(", ")", "User name (sales)")
        }
```

Here is an example:

```
string Substring = GetSubstringByString(<html content>,<other html content>,<what i need>)
```